# import ortools in mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, conda, or-tools

I am trying to run some code using ortools on a python environment. I did not have troubles on a windows machine but I am having problems on mac (10.12.6). if in my virtual environment I run

```
pip freeze
```

or

```
conda list
```

ortools appears in my list of installed packages. But if I try to use it

```
ipython
from ortools.linear_solver import pywrapplp
```

I get an error saying that there's no module named ortools. If I go to

mac/anaconda3/envs/nameenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages I do have a folder called ortools with some python files including pywrapplp. Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

following request from coments:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

returns '/Users/imac'

```
which ipython
```

/anaconda3/bin/ipython

Installing ortools is a bit of a headache. It was some days ago, I think I finally made it with

```
easy_install ortools
```

I think it is a problem with the path. I guess because I did not install it with conda it does not find the package. I got around writting:

```
sys.path.append('/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

at the begining of my ipynb. That way I can run ortools.

Comment: what do you get when you ran `import os,
os.getcwd() ` in your ipython ?

Comment: What is the output of `which ipython`? Did you install ipython into your environment?

Comment: i just tried installing ortools but got "no package found".  How did you install ortools?

Answer (score 0):

You could have several python interpreter installed (python2 and python3)

So if you want to use it with `ipython`, which seems to be bind on python3 in your case.

First check if you have pypi package [ortools](https://pypi.org/project/ortools/) installed

`ipython -m pip show ortools`

If you got an error it means the package is not installed.

so you can easily install it using:

`ipython -m pip install --user ortools`

note: We provide Pypi `ortools` package (64 bits) for Manylinux, Windows and MacOS.
You can also rebuild it from source https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/installing/source